# Launch Daemon Listen for NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd, nsapplication, nsworkspace

I have a launch daemon and I would like it to run a function every time an application launches.

I'm currently using `NSWorkspace` to check for the launch of applications.

## parasited.plist in */Library/LaunchDaemons/*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>parasited</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/parasited</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

## parasited *main.m*

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]notificationCenter]addObserver:[[Parasited alloc] init] selector:@selector(inject) name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification object:nil];

        }
}
```

It seems like my process, `parasited` keeps restarting and I can't figure out why.
My goal is to run a function everytime an app such as "Safari, Mail, Finder, etc" launches.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing saying to main that it needs to hang around. You want a run loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application has no central [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html) in which to loop and wait for notifications.

As an experiment, add a `CFRunLoopRun()` call after your NSWorkspace call. [CFRunLoopRun](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRun) will loop until the process is terminated.

See Matt Gallagher's [demystifying NSApplication by recreating it](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html) post to learn more about the run loop and the role it plays in keeping your application running and processing events.